# How to make sequalize createTable support underscore?

Tags: format, sequelize.js

I was trying to use sequalize seed to initialize the table rows, but I got error return:

> column "createdAt" of relation "users" does not exist

It actually is "created_at" as the field, so my question is that how can I seed the table with snake or underscore option?

My seed code as following:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.bulkInsert(
      "users",
      [
        {
          firstname: "John",
          lastname: "Doe",
          email: "demo@demo.com",
          createdAt: new Date(),
          updatedAt: new Date()
        }
      ],
      {}
    );
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.bulkDelete("users", null, {});
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pass those information while defining your configurations for database connection like below.

```
'use strict';
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};
let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
    config.define = {
      "timestamps":true,
      "createdAt":"created_at",
      "updatedAt":"updated_at"
  }
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password,config );
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

Here `config` is your db configuration. You add other configuration on a separate `define`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see all in a [documentation](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html) **queryInterface** methods work with tables and not models so you should use real column names instead of model props.

Comment: it seems queryInterface doesn't have any options on underscore but the model, so we have to create the model for bulk insertion if we want to use underscore options.